# Assembler error when using 'dccmvac' in a kernel module

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi3

When I try to compile the following code in a kernel module on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (ARMv8a, AARCH32), I get a 'bad instruction' error. According to ARM Reference Manual for ARMv8a, this instruction is undefined at Exception Level 0 (EL0) for AARCH32, but I'm using it in a kernel module so I don't understand the issue.

```
__asm(
"mov r9,%0 \n\t"
"mov r10,%1 \n\t"
"mov r1,#0 \n\t
"str r1,[r9] \n\t"
"str r1,[r10] \n\t"
"DCCMVAC r9 \n\t"
"DCCMVAC r10 \n\t"
:
:"r" (firstPtr),
 "r" (secondPtr)
:"r1","r9","r10","memory"
);
```

The assembly-related message is as follows,

```
/tmp/ccCmW5TY.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccCmW5TY.s:221: Error: bad instruction `dccmvac r9'
/tmp/ccCmW5TY.s:222: Error: bad instruction `dccmvac r10'
```

Comment: Hard-coding r9 and r10 in your inline-asm statement means you need to declare a clobber on those registers.  Also, you don't ask the compiler to put anything in `r0`, so there's no way this asm fragment can be part of a non-broken program.  (Note that using any operands in a `naked` function is not officially supported, so this shouldn't be the entire body of a `naked` function with stuff in r0 from the calling convention.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. The code is just part of a raw assembly program that I put in a kernel module to test whether the bad instruction error goes away at a higher privilege level. So the code is not intended to work as inline assembly.

Comment: In that case I would have made a [mcve] with a `.S` file, instead of fake inline asm.

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DCCMVAC` instruction is likely not recognized by `GNU as`:
According to Arm documentation, the `DCCMVAC` instruction is being performed by performing an operation on the `CP15` coprocessor:

```
MCR{<c>}{<q>} <coproc>, {#}<opc1>, <Rt>, <CRn>, <CRm>{, {#}<opc2>} 
with the following values:
coproc  opc1    CRn     CRm     opc2
0b1111  0b000   0b0111  0b1010  0b001
```

There is an implementation in the `CMSIS_5` project in the form of the following define/function/macro, in files `CMSIS/Core_A/Include/cmsis_gcc.h` and `CMSIS/Core_A/Include/cmsis_cp15.h`.

We can re-use some code for building an example program `dccmvac.c`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
  
#define __ASM                                  __asm
#define __set_CP(cp, op1, Rt, CRn, CRm, op2) __ASM volatile("MCR p" # cp ", " # op1 ", %0, c" # CRn ", c" # CRm ", " # op2 : : "r" (Rt) : "memory" )
#define __STATIC_FORCEINLINE                   __attribute__((always_inline)) static inline

/** \brief  Set DCCMVAC
    
  Data cache clean
 */
__STATIC_FORCEINLINE void __set_DCCMVAC(uint32_t value)
{
  __set_CP(15, 0, value, 7, 10, 1);
}

int main()
{
  __set_DCCMVAC(0x12345678U);

  return 0;
}


/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -o dccmvac.o dccmvac.c
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -D  dccmvac.o



dccmvac.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   e52db004        push    {fp}            ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000        add     fp, sp, #0
   8:   e24dd00c        sub     sp, sp, #12
   c:   e59f3020        ldr     r3, [pc, #32]   ; 34 <main+0x34>
  10:   e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
  14:   e51b3008        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
  18:   ee073f3a        mcr     15, 0, r3, cr7, cr10, {1}
  1c:   e1a00000        nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)
  20:   e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
  24:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
  28:   e28bd000        add     sp, fp, #0
  2c:   e49db004        pop     {fp}            ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  30:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
  34:   12345678        eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12        ; 0x7800000
```

Value `0x123456781`  is being loaded into `r3`prior to `mcr 15, 0, r3, cr7, cr10, {1}` being executed.

Disassembling `0xee073f3a`using `shell-storm` gives:

`0x0000000000000000:  EE 07 3F 3A    mcr p15, #0, r3, c7, c10, #1`

You should now have the information you need to use the `DCCMVAC` instruction in your code  - just keep in mind that Arm `CMSIS_5` code is licensed under the Apache-2.0 license, and therefore cannot just be copied/pasted into a Linux kernel module - you should probably use the Linux `dccmvac` macro defined in `arch/arm/mm/cache-v7m.S` instead, or write your own equivalent code.

Comment: Where do you specify r3 as an argument of MCR? My understanding is that in your code, the value 0x12345678U is assigned to Rt, while I was expecting it to be something like R3.

Comment: In Arm documentation, Rt is a symbolic notation used a a shortcut to say that any general purpose register can used by the instruction. That is, when you see Rt mentioned, you can replace <t> by 3 , which means R3 will be the actual register that will be used. I don't see the the assembly code any reference to Rt, just one to R3. The code was generated by the C compiler from `__set_DCCMVAC(0x12345678U);`. that is, the compiler decided to use 3 as the value for <t>, i.e. to use the R3 register. Does this answer your question ?